# NPM - Difference between facebook-bot-messenger & messenger-node

Tags: node.js, express, npm, node-modules, facebook-messenger-bot

Can anyone please tell me the difference between these two modules :

- `facebook-bot-messenger`
- `messenger-node`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Different implementation FB api

- facebook-bot-messenger uses graph version 2.8
- messenger-node uses graph version 2.11, also more active

Also [messenger-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/messenger-node?activeTab=dependencies) requires `express` to work.

Get to know your needs and then choose the implementation.